# Find the angles of given triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, angle

> A triangle $ABC$ with angle bisectors $AA_1$ and $BB_1$ is given, such that $\angle AA_1B_1 = 24^\circ$ and $\angle BB_1A_1 = 18^\circ$. Find the angles of the triangle.

I've been stuck on this one for quite a long time. After denoting with $I$ the incenter of ABC and deriving that $\angle C = 96^\circ$ from $\angle AIB = 90^\circ + \frac12\angle C = 138^\circ$, I really don't know how to continue. I tried using Geogebra to see everything clearer or at least guess the answer, and I concluded that $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ should be $12^\circ$ and $72^\circ$ respectively, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated. If I come up with something, I will post it right away. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. 
Please take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: The problem doesn't look so simple (though, it seems trig-bashable), is it from a TST for an olympiad?

Comment: I saw the problem in a JBMO TST in AoPS, but unfortunately no one had posted a solution :(
I also considered trying something with trigonometry, although as it is from a JBMO TST, I believe it's supposed to be solved without trig-bashing.

Comment: By the way can we find the values of trigonometric ratios of 24°?

Comment: Does it help reflecting some angles because $24×2 = \frac{96}{2}$?

Comment: Taking a look at [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/clwgbl/an_interesting_geometry_problem/) might be unveiling.

Comment: Using trig to solve this kind of problem will be the easiest method to think...

Comment: A pure geometric proof is given in AoPS (found it by searching in AoPS) : #3 in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h386177p2144437

Comment: @ACB It is in IMO shortlist 1992, P11,https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3943_1992_imo_shortlist

Comment: @RiverLi there is also a duplicate here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211010/947379

Answer (score 4):

Observe: $2(18°)+24° = \color{red}{60°}$. This hints that maybe producing $18°$ might help. Let $A_1$, $B_1$ respectively denote the point of intersection of angle bisectors from A, B to corresponding sides. Since $\angle ABB_1 = \angle CBB_1$, reflect $∆BA_1B_1$ about side $BB_1$. Let the reflection of $A_1$ on AB be $A'$. Due to the property of reflection, $∆BB_1A_1 ≅ ∆BB_1A'$. Let X denote the point of intersection of $A'A_1$ and $BB_1$. $∆A_1XB ≅ ∆A'XB$, so

$\angle A_1XB = \angle A'XB = \frac{180°}{2} = 90°$.

Therefore,
$\angle XA_1A = 90° -(18°+24°) = 48°$

. Observe that $48° = \color{red}{2}×24°$. Since $\angle A_1AB = \angle A_1AC$ reflection $∆A_1AA'$ about line $A_1A$. Let the reflection of $A'$ be $A''$.

$\angle A''A_1A = \angle A'A_1A = 48°$.

Therefore $\angle A''A_1B_1 = 24°$. Let Y denote the point of intersection of $A'B_1$ and $AA_1$. $∆A_1YA' ≅ ∆A_1YA''$. Therefore

$\angle A_1YA'' = \angle A_1YA' = 180°-48°-(90°-18°) = 60°$.

Also $\angle B_1YA = \angle A_1YA' = 60°$. Therefore $\angle B_1YA'' = 180-2×60° = 60°$. Extend $A_1A''$ to a point Z. Observe $B_1$ lies on the angle bisectors of $\angle A''A_1Y$ and $\angle A''YA$. Therefore $A''B_1$ is the angle bisector of $\angle YA''Z$. therefore

$\angle YA''B_1 = 0.5 × (60°+48°) = 54°$.

Therefore

$\angle A_1B_1A'' = 180°-(24°+54°+72°) = 30°$.

$\angle A_1B_1A''$ is exterior angle to $∆A_1B_1A$ therefore $\angle A_1AB_1 = (30°-24°) = 6°$. Therefore $A= 12°$, $B = 72°$, $C=96°$.[image: Diagram]

Comment: What does $(90^o-18^o)$ represent in $\angle A_1YA'' = \angle A_1YA' = 180^o-48^o-(90^o-18^o) = 60^o$ ?

Comment: $\angle A_1YA' = 180° - \angle YA_1A' - \angle A_1A'Y$. $\angle A'XB_1 = 90°$, $\angle XB_1A' = 18°$, so $\angle A_1A'Y = (90°-18°)$

Answer (score 2):

This is not difficult if you use the incenter's property.

Let $\angle CAB=2\alpha$ and $\angle CBA=2\beta$. As we can easily get $\angle C=96^\circ$ we have $\alpha+\beta=42^\circ$.

By the law of sines, we have

$$\frac{IB_1}{IA_1}=\frac{\sin 24^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ}$$

Now we draw perpendicular lines of $IX\perp CA$ and $IY\perp CB$. Since $I$ is incenter, we have $IX=IY$, and thus

$$\frac{\sin 24^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ}=\frac{IB_1}{IA_1}=\frac{IX/\sin(\angle CB_1B)}{IY/\sin(\angle CA_1A)}=\frac{\sin(\angle CA_1A)}{\sin(\angle CB_1B)}=\frac{\sin(2\beta+\alpha)}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}$$

Since $\alpha+\beta=42^\circ$, we have $3(\alpha+\beta)=126^\circ$, thus

$$\frac{\sin(2\beta+\alpha)}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin(126^\circ-(2\alpha+\beta))}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}=\sin 126^\circ \cot(2\alpha+\beta)-\cos 126^\circ$$

Notice that $2\alpha+\beta<2(\alpha+\beta)=84^\circ<90^\circ$, we can see $\sin 126^\circ \cot(2\alpha+\beta)-\cos 126^\circ$ as a function of $2\alpha+\beta$ that is monotone in $(0,90^\circ)$. Thus, if we know the function value (which is $\frac{\sin 24^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ}$), there is a unique angle $2\alpha+\beta$. So we can know that there is at most one solution (there is at most one shape). If there is a triangle with ($2\alpha+\beta$) such that

$$\frac{\sin 24^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ}=\frac{\sin(2\beta+\alpha)}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin(126^\circ-(2\alpha+\beta))}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)},$$

then that triangle is the desired solution. Now we only need to prove the triangle you proposed satisfies this. That is, if $\angle A=12^\circ$ and $\angle B=72^\circ$ satisfies, this is the only solution.

In this case, $\alpha=6^\circ$, $\beta=36^\circ$. Thus we only need to prove

$$\frac{\sin 24^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ}=\frac{\sin(2\beta+\alpha)}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin 78^\circ}{\sin 48^\circ}.$$

Or, $$\frac{\sin 24^\circ \sin 48^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ \sin 78^\circ} = 1.$$

This can be proved by following:
$$\frac{\sin 24^\circ \sin 48^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ \sin 78^\circ}=\frac{2\sin 12^\circ \cos 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ \sin 78^\circ}=\frac{2\sin 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ}{\sin 18^\circ}=\frac{2\sin(30^\circ-18^\circ)\sin(30^\circ+18^\circ)}{\sin 18^\circ}=\frac{2(\sin^2 30^\circ- \sin^2 18^\circ)}{\sin 18^\circ}=\frac{2(\frac{1}{4}- (\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4})^2)}{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}=\frac{2(\frac{1}{4}- \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{8})}{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}=1.$$

Thus, the problem is solved.

---

A friend of mine suggested a geometric method:

Consider the lines

[image: The graph of lemms]

Let a 12-gon $ADEFGHBH'G'F'E'D'A$ (as the figure shows in red lines). twelve liines (in the red) are equal lengths and the angles are: $\angle A=36^\circ$, $\angle D=\angle D'=108^\circ$, $\angle E=\angle E'=12^\circ$, $\angle F=\angle F'=\angle G=\angle G'=24^\circ$, $\angle H=\angle H'=84^\circ$, $\angle B=60^\circ$. One could check, if we go from $A$, and walk through all other vertices along those angles, one will return $A$. This is because (check the angles (don't use the condition $\angle A=36^\circ$, use other angles to derive) and leave as exercise) $\vec{EF}+\vec{G'F'}=0$, $\vec{FG}+\vec{F'E'}=0$, $\vec{DE}+\vec{HB}+\vec{BH'}=0$ (because they are equilateral triangle), and $\vec{AD}+\vec{E'D'}+\vec{D'A}+\vec{H'G'}+\vec{GH}=0$ (because they are regular pentagon.) So this equilateral 12-gon exists and notice that it is symmetry along $AB$, we have $\angle BAD=18^\circ$ and $\angle HBA=150^\circ$.

Then construct $C$ that $GHB$ and $GFC$ are congruent. So we have $\angle EFC=84^\circ$ and thus $\angle EFC=24^\circ+84^\circ=108^\circ=\angle EDA$. So triangle $EDA$ and triangle $EFC$ are congruent. Therefore we have $EA=EC$, $GB=GC$.

We construct $Q$ to be the symmetric point with respect to $EG$. So $EA=EC=EQ$ and $GB=GC=GQ$. So $E$ is the circumcenter of $ACQ$ and $G$ is the circumcenter of $BCQ$. So
$$\angle BQC=\angle BGC/2 =\angle HGF/2=12^\circ$$
$$\angle AQC=\angle AEC/2 =\angle FED/2=6^\circ$$
Therefore we have $\angle AQB=6^\circ$
Also we have $\angle FEC=36^\circ$ and $\angle FEG=78^\circ$. Therefore we have
$$\angle QAC=\angle QEC/2=\angle GEC=\angle FEG-\angle FEC=42^\circ$$
Also we have $\angle QEC=2\angle GEC=84^\circ$ and $\angle AEC=12^\circ$
$$\angle QAE=90^\circ-(\angle QEA/2)=90^6\circ-(\angle QEC+\angle CEA)/2=90^\circ-(84^\circ+12^\circ)/2=42^\circ$$
So
$$\angle BAQ=\angle BAD+\angle DAE+\angle EAQ=18^\circ+36^\circ+42^\circ=96^\circ$$
So $\angle BAC=96^\circ+42^\circ=138^\circ$

Also we have $\angle EGC=\angle EGF+\angle FGC=90^\circ-24^\circ/2+90^\circ-84^\circ/2=126^\circ$, and $\angle GEC=42^\circ$, so $\angle ECG=180^\circ-\angle EGC - \angle GEC=12^\circ$. Since $GB=GC$ and $\angle BGC=24^\circ$, we have $\angle GCB=28^\circ$, so $\angle ECB=66^\circ$. Also, we have $EA=EC$ and $\angle AEC=12^\circ$, we have $\angle ECA=84^\circ$, and thus $\angle BCA=18^\circ$. Therefore we have $\angle ABC=24^\circ$

So we have the configuration: $\angle ABC=24^\circ$, $\angle BCA=18^\circ$, $\angle BAQ=96^\circ$ $\angle QAC=42^\circ$, $\angle BQA=6^\circ$
and $\angle AQC=6^\circ$.

Now we let the circumcircle of $BCQ$ having another intersection of $AQ$, call it $P$. So we have $\angle PBC=\angle PCB=6^\circ$. Thus, we can proof the following lemma:

If the triangle $ABC$ satisfy $\angle B=24^\circ$, $\angle C=18^\circ$, and the interior $P$ such that $\angle PBC=\angle PCB=6^\circ$. We have $\angle PAB=96^\circ$, $\angle PBA=42^\circ$.

This can be proved by the "identity method" and the things above.

Now we turn to the original problem:
[image: Original problem]

Let $P$ be the circumcenter of $B_1CA_1$. Since we have $\angle B_1A_1I=24^\circ$ and $\angle A_1B_1I=18^\circ$, we have $\angle B_1IC_1=138^\circ$, and thus $\angle C=96^\circ$. Therefore, we know that $P$ is the same side with $I$ with respect to $A_1B_1$ and $\angle PA_1B_1=\angle PB_1A_1=6^\circ$. By the lemma above, we have $\angle PIB_1=42^\circ$.

Let $D$ be the intersection of $CI$ and the circumcircle of $CA_1B_1$. We have $\angle PDB_1=\angle B_1DA_1 /2=(180^\circ-\angle C)/2=42^\circ$. Since $\angle PIB_1=42^\circ$, we have $B_1,P,I,D$ four points on a circle. Therefore $\angle PDC=\angle PB_1I=12^\circ$. So we have $\angle CA_1B_1=\angle CDB_1=\angle PDB_1+\angle CDP=54^\circ$. Therefore we know that $\angle CA_1A=24^\circ+54^\circ=78^\circ$ and thus $\angle CAA_1=180^\circ-78^\circ-96^\circ=6^\circ$, so $\angle CAB=12^\circ$, and $\angle ABC=72^\circ$

Comment: I wanted to celebrate your answer but what you have really did is to verify (not out of wit I admit!) that the given answer by the O.P. is true. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Verifying is the last step... The previous steps are proving the uniqueness of the solution. If we find a solution and verify it correct, then that is the only solution... Using trig to solve these problems are a common way if the pure geometric method is hard to think... But I am also figuring out a geometric method.

Comment: Dear friend: my viewpoint on your solution can be explayed as follows: Can you solve the equation in two unknowns  $a=\dfrac{\sin(2x+y)}{\sin(2y+x)}$ without knowing the solution before?. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Dear friend: So basically, what you are asking of solving equation is to calculate $\arctan (\frac{\sin 18^\circ}{\sin 24^\circ \sin 54^\circ}-\tan 36^\circ)$. Without noticing the P. O.'s solution, typing it into a calculator we can see it is $12^\circ$. And what we should do is to prove it to be. Of course, it is nearly impossible for me to work by hand what that is without firstly figuring out/guessing out what it is. One way to get it out by hand is to first calculate how much it is, then "Round to the nearest $6^\circ$". Regards.

Comment: @JetfiRex: Your assertion about "Round to the nearest $6^{\circ}$ in a non-countable world seems to me not admisible. I would suggest ending this conversation. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a kind of reverse approach, beginning with the triangle Euclid uses to construct the regular pentagon.  To avoid confusion, and aid comparison, I keep OP's lettering.

Construct triangle $B_1A_1E$ as the $36^o-72^o-72^o$ triangle of *Elements* IV, 10.

Let $B_1F$ bisect $\angle EB_1A_1$, and make $\angle B_1A_1I=24^o$. Thus $\angle IB_1A_1=\frac{36}{2}=18^o$.

Next make $\angle B_1ID=\angle DIC=42^o$, and make $IC=IB_1$.

Join and extend $CB_1$ to meet $A_1I$ extended at $A$, and join and extend $AE$ and $CA_1$ to meet at $B$.

Since $\angle AIF=138^o$, and if, as OP notes, $\angle ACB=2(138^o-90^o)=96^o$, while $\angle DCI=180^o-(90^o+42^o)=48^o$, therefore also $\angle ICA_1= 48^o$, $CI$ bisects $\angle ACB$, and the incenter of $\triangle ABC$ lies somewhere on $CI$.

Next, dropping perpendiculars $IG$, $IH$, triangles $HIE$ and $GIA_1$ are congruent. For since $\angle DIA=B_1IA+DIB_1=(18+24)+42^o=84^o$, making $\angle AIE=\angle A_1ID=96^o$, while $\angle GID=84^o$, therefore$$\angle A_1IG=96^o-84^o=12^o$$
[image: Angles in triangle ABC]
In like manner$$\angle HIE=\angle AIE-\angle AIH=96^o-84^o=12^o$$

And since by symmetry $IA_1=IE$, then triangles $HIE$ and $GIA_1$ are congruent and$$IH=IG=ID$$

$I$ is thus the incenter of $\triangle ABC$, and $IA$ bisects $\angle CAB$.

And again, since $\angle DIA=84^o$, and $\angle ADI= 90^o$, therefore$$\angle IAD=6^o$$making$$\angle BAC=12^o$$and$$\angle CBA=72^o$$

Comment: Sorry... but I could not follow the 6th line of your proof... So why $\angle ACB=96^{\circ}$ by your construction (you said "if, as OP notes..." but I still can't see why, because I don't know from your construction why till 6th line why $CI$ is the bisector of $\angle ACB$)? Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: If OP's inference that $\angle ACB=96^o$ pre-supposes that $CI$ bisects $\angle ACB$, then I'm afraid my reasoning here is circular. I wondered about this too, but OP didn't give details on this and no one else questioned or commented.  Thank you for bringing the matter up.  The flaw may be fatal to my approach.